# .htaccess redirect to specific port, without changing URL

Tags: .htaccess, url, redirect

I want to redirect `example.org/folder` to `example.org:3000` without changing the URL.

My .htaccess is in /folder:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^example\.org$ [OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\.example\.org$
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^http://example.org:3000/
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://example.org:3000/$1 [P]
```

It works, but the URL changes.